# UIView is hidding section title in tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to show a button over a tableView section header: I am using a UIView to host the button, but it is overlapping the section title. This is the viewForHeaderInSection method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    static NSString *header = @"customHeader";

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *vHeader;

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    NSString *tmp = [theSection name];
    NSLog(@"SECTIONNAME = %@",tmp);

    vHeader = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:header];
    NSLog(@"SECTION = %ld",(long)section);

    if (!vHeader) {
        vHeader = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:header];
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    if (section == 0) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    else if (section == 1) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    else if (section == 2) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    else if (section == 3) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
    }
    else if (section == 4) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else if (section == 5) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    }

    vHeader.textLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];


    UIView *mView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 44.0f)];
    [mView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 20, 20)];
    [logoView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"carat.png"]];
    [mView addSubview:logoView];

    UIButton *bt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [bt setFrame:CGRectMake(210, 0, 150, 30)];
    [bt setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [bt setTag:section];
    [bt.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
    [bt.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [bt.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [bt setTitle: @"More Info" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [bt addTarget:self action:@selector(addCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mView addSubview:bt];
    return mView;

    return vHeader;

}
```

What should I do to keep the section title and also show the button. The section title is defined in the `titleForHeaderInSection` method?

EDITED:

Screenshot with normal section titles

[image]

Screenshot with hide section titles, UIVIew is overlapping:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're describing?

Comment: Thank you @stewart715, I have posted two screenshots, one with the normal section titles, and the second with the UIView hidding the section titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your button is just too big. Try to reduce the height and font size of it and it should work. You could also increase the height of a section header with the following method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30;
}
```

**Edit:**
You can achieve your behaviour like this:

```
//create the regular section header
if (regularHeader) {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 28)];
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 300, 20)];
    titleLabel.text = title;
    [headerView addSubview:titleLabel];
    return headerView;
}

//create the header with the more button
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIButton *moreButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, 0, 50, 30)];
moreButton.titleLabel.text = @"More";
[headerView addSubview:moreButton];
return headerView;
```

Comment: I guess that the problem is not the button size but the UIView size or position...

Comment: sounds reasonable ;) you can also check in `heightForHeaderInSection` which view you'll return in `viewForHeaderInSection` and return the corresponding height

Comment: You can check it in my question, it is:  UIView *mView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];This view is hosting the button.

Comment: is it possible to put a button on a section header with no need to use a UIView?

Comment: I always create my section headers with a UIView (without `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier`). Create a UIView with a frame `CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, YOUR-HEIGHT)` and add your Labels, Buttons as desired. Just make sure that you return the same `YOUR-HEIGHT` in `heightForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: I am creating the UIView like you said, but the section title is not shown, the UIView is like an overlay on the section header title.

Comment: May be the problem is the way I am getting the section title.

Comment: look at my edited answer, i put some sample code for the header views

Comment: it is not working in any case...but I guess that the problem lies on the way I am obtaining the section title from the titleForHeaderInSection method.